# Writing a size() method for a User-defined Stack Class

Tags: stack, size

I'm writing a program that requires the length/size of a stack. Because I am not importing the Stack class (and I've made my own - see below) I don't know how to make a method that calculates the size of the stack and returns that integer value. Here's the Stack class so far:

```
public class Stack<String> implements StackInter<String>
{
    public void push(String x)
    { // This method is written
    }
    public String pop()
    { // This method is written
    }
    public boolean isEmptyStack()
    { // This method is written
    }
    public String peek()
    { // This method is written
    }

    public int size()
    {
        // What goes in here!
    }
}
```

This is where I want to use the size method

```
public class InfixCalculator
{
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    int size = stack.size();
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pseudo code is somthing like this:

```
    public class Stack<String> implements StackInter<String>
    {
        private size;
        //constructor 
        public Stack<String>(){
        size=0;

        }
        public void push(String x)
        { // This method is written
          size++;
        }
        public String pop()
        { // This method is written
          if(size > 0 )
            size--;
        }
        public boolean isEmptyStack()
        { // This method is written
        }
        public String peek()
        { // This method is written


        }

        public int size()
        {
           int theSize=size;
           return theSize;

        }
    }
```

after you apply your operations the size can be computed.

Answer (score 0):

If your Stack is an array write

```
public int size() {
  return array.length;
}
```

Comment: What if your stack is not an array?

Comment: he didn't mention which type it is